# Saving UIPickerView data to CoreData - Swift 3

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, xcode8, uipickerview

I am trying to save a selected row from a custom `UIPickerView` loaded with data from an `NSFetchRequest` in CoreData. All of my `dataSource` functions are set up correctly to the best of my knowledge, and I now am stuck on attempting to save a `Formula` object. A `Formula` object can have one `Service` object. The custom `UIPickerView` is fetching all of the `Service` objects.

Currently this is what my save function looks like.

```
@IBAction func saveFormulaButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if let formula = self.formula {
        formula.text = formulaText.text
        formula.date = formulaDatePicker.date as NSDate
        formula.isCheckedIn = formulaCheckInSwitch.isOn

        formula.service = [Don't know what goes here??]

    } else if let client = client {
        guard let text = formulaText.text else { return }
        let newFormula = Formula(client: client, text: text, service: ??, isCheckedIn: formulaCheckInSwitch.isOn, service:  date: formulaDatePicker.date)
        FormulaController.sharedController.addFormula(newFormula)
    }
    let _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Where `formula.service` is, I do not know what goes there. I want to grab the selected row from the custom `UIPickerView` and need it to match up with `formula.service` but I do not know how to go about it.

Comment: Do you have a service object in your class where this function is defined?please show some more code

Comment: Please show the code for the custom UIPickerView datasource methods.